# Using jQuery to adjust "transform: translate3d" based on container width

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following jQuery to adjust the height of a div based on its width:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(window).bind("load resize",function(e){
      jQuery(".showcase .image_container").css('height', jQuery(".showcase .image_container").width()/'1.7438');
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is working well but I'd like to use "transform: translate3d" to move the image inside this div up on hover:

```
.showcase .image_container:hover img { transform: translate3d(0px, -150px, 0px); }
```

How can I use jQuery to adjust the Y value (150px) based on the width of the .image_container. i.e.

.image-container width / 3.2667

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach an event handler for `mouseover/mouseout` and do what you need within that.

See **[this jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/ryL9ur4u/)**.

Relevant code is:

```
var timerID;

$('.showcase .image_container img').on('mouseover', function () {
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    $(this).css('transform', 'translate3d(0px, -' + $('.showcase .image_container img').width()/3.2667 + 'px, 0px)');
}).on('mouseout', function (e) {
    var self = this;
    timerID = setTimeout(function () {
        $(self).css('transform', 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Why the `setTimeout()`? Otherwise, you run into the problem of the `mouseout` triggering when the image moves up and the cursor out of it.